# Struggling to design R2 to simple circuit specifiations

Tags: resistance, ohms-law, nodal-analysis

[image: Circuit design - analog electronics]

I have set up a nodal equation such that all currents are entering the center node (\$V_x\$):

$$\frac{V_1-V_x}{R_1} + \frac{V_2-V_x}{R_2} + \frac{V_3-V_x}{R_3} = 0 \to \frac{V_1-V_x}{R_1} + I_2 + \frac{V_3-V_x}{R_3} = 0$$

I've solved for \$V_x = 2.05\text{ V}\$ using the given current and then solved for \$R_2 = 2.136\text{ k}\Omega\$ but this was incorrect.

I'm not sure if the method is wrong or where I went wrong so I could really use some help.

Comment: 2.05V should be the correct value for Vx or close enough; how are you getting to R2 from that?

Comment: I used the same equation once I had found Vx and instead of changing (v2-Vx)/R2 to the given I2. I resolved the equation using (V2-Vx)/R2 solving for R2

Comment: Vx is exactly 2.0625V, so R2 = (4.2-Vx)/1.1mA

Comment: That was correct, thank you. I don't know what I was thinking subbing vx back in, instead of simply using Ohm's law

Comment: I think you've made an arithmetic error somewhere.  Vx = +2.0625V, R2= 1.94K  and incidentally the current through R1 is 1.3125mA and that through R3 must be 2.4125mA